# Facebook: Share using Facebook app icon and "using such and such app" text

Tags: facebook

On our website we would like to allow users to share content that they have read.  We would like them to be able to click a "Share" button, which would then link up with our Facebook app.

So, the final post to the wall would be something like:

> "I just saw this great deal!!"
>
> [our icon] Today at 1pm via My
>   Application Name

Now, we can easily do this from our iPhone app using the Facebook iOS sdk, but how can we do this same sort of thing from our website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do that, you will have to use the [SDK of your choice](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/) and then make a FB Connect to your app, [ask for permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) to post in the users wall and then [write a post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) into his wall.

You can customize text, and action buttons, and it will appear with your app icon as you request.

Answer (score 1):

You add `opengraph` tags to your site, specifically `og:image`

Have a look at: [Open Graph protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Like button api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). That is replacing or has replaced the share functionality. You can add that to your site and when a user clicks it, it will show up in their feeding saying they "like xyz" with whatever comment they enter.

Comment: Yes, we are already doing this. But I want it to show our app icon and name below the post.  I have seen many other apps do this, such as annoying ones like Farmville.